# android fragment missing from View Hierarchy

Tags: android, view, android-fragments

I have two fragments in an activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        class="com.eyecreate.fragment1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="269dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fragment1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/fragment1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fragment1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        class="com.eyecreate.fragment2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"></fragment>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment1 doesn't show up on screen and isn't on the Hierarchy Viewer, but has an instance in code that still has calls to onCreate run on it. fragment2 shows up and takes up the whole screen. What could be causing it to have just disappeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling kinda dumb, I had a call to 
    getActivity().setContentView(fragment2)
during the onresume of that fragment. That would be causing the fragment2 to be the only one showing up.

Answer (score 0):

The `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes for the `fragment2` is `match_parent`. Thats the reason it is taking up whole screen.

I think you wanted to use `LinearLayout` and not `RelativeLayout`. the `android:orientation` doesn't make sense for `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: changing the width values and layout to Linear didn't change how things showed up.